# How to calculate signature according input query param when I use karate?

Tags: karate

When I use https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client, I calculator signature method is:

```
client.preparePost(host + uri + query)
        .addFormParam("photo_id", "123456")
        .addFormParam("user_id", "7890")
        .addFormParam("token", "helloworld")
        .addFormParam("os", 'ios')
        .setSignatureCalculator(sign) // inject calculator class
        .execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>() {
            @Override
            public Response onCompleted(Response response) {
                Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), 200);
                return response;
            }
        })
        .toCompletableFuture()
        .join()
```

Above the code, we know every request before will calculate sign.

But, when use karate, how should I do? thanks!

And because every request need to calculate signature according query param and form data, so I hope the calculate can execute on base class/method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `async-http-client` but pretty sure this just OAuth authentication. So just refer to this example: [`oauth2.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature)

So the above example is when you get the OAuth token by making an HTTP request to the server.

But in case you only have the keys and secrets (OAuth 1?) - then you have to use Java to do the step of calculating the signature, and this is currently not built-in to Karate. Looks like we have to write code similar to this: [`OAuthSignatureCalculatorInstance.java`](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/oauth/OAuthSignatureCalculatorInstance.java)

You may already know that Karate has very good support for re-using Java .

No one has requested this till now so I am assuming that it is always possible for HTTP clients to make an additional request to get the `Authorization` header, so you don't need to calculate it.